# Unity3d проблема с покупками в Amazon магазине

Tags: android, unity3d, amazon

1. Использую стандартный юнитишный плагин.
2. Покупки в Google Play работают (это я к тому, что реализацию сделал правильно).
3. Когда пытаюсь использовать Amazon покупки, то проблема.

   - Список доступных покупок получается норм.
   - Инициируется покупка норм.
   - После покупки ничего не происходит. Деньги не снимают, колбек в юнити коде не отрабатывает. Ошибок в логах нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Обновил сам плагин до новой версии.
2. В `AndroidManifest.xml` дописал ресивер, как указано в [доках](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/cross-platform-plugins/cpp-add-plugin-to-unity-project.html):

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
       <action
         android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
         android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
     </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```

Немного странно, что в [доках юнити](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPAmazonConfiguration.html) про ресивер ни слова.

Comment: Было бы отлично кинуть репорт на страничку с докой юнити, может исправят

Comment: @MikhailEfremov кидал (: